# How does CURL extract labels from logits?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, deep-learning, papers, pytorch, unsupervised-learning

While going over the pseudocode of the [CURL paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2004.04136.pdf), the method to identify labels from the logits wasn't clear to me.  I believe this technique might be common in other PyTorch/Deep Learning tasks. I have attached the pseudocode below -

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given `arange` returns a 1-D tensor with values from `0` to `logits.shape[0]`, then the labels is a vector of $0$ to $N$ where $N$ is the number of classes predicted by the output layer of `f_q`.

The CrossEntropyLoss then finds the difference between the predictions and the target labels, which the encoder weights `f_q.params` is updated according to. I haven't read the paper, but this particular part is a standard [multi-class classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiclass_classification) approach.